# PHP Session MVC using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

So i have been developing a simple login and insert data pages using CodeIgniter, i want to every user has their own data kept in DB and every user has their own set of-DB. My focus here is to get the session first, because  i can't get the session from my code.

I am new to PHP and never use PHP even the native one before. Here is my Controller:

```
    public function login(){
    $this->load->library('session');
    $email  = $this->input->post('email');
    $password  = $this->input->post('password');    
    log_message('error','isi email : '.$email);
    log_message('error','isi password : '.$password);
    $return = $this->welcome_model->checkLogin($email, $password);

    if($return){
    $this->session->set_userdata('email',$email);
    $var = $this->session->userdata;
    redirect('welcome/masuk');}
```

Model:

```
public function checkLogin($email, $password)
{
    $return = $this->db->get_where('login',array('email'=>$email, 'password' => $password));

    if($return->result_array() != NULL){

        return TRUE;

    }else{ 

        return FALSE;

    }

}
```

View:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/login" method="post">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
    </form>
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: There can be no real answer to this question. You're basically looking for a code review, and that's not what Stack Overflow is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, i think you need to look into following points while considering making login page :-

```
 1. $this->load->library('session');  //Try to put this in autoload.php in application/config.
    $autoload['libraries'] = array('session');

2. <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/login" method="post">
   You can replace this in view with 
   <?= form_open() ?>....CODE....<?= form_close() ?>

3. Try to use form-validation rules something like this
   $this->form_validation->set_rules(
        'title', 
        'Title', 
        'required|min_length[20]');
```

And yes for separating all the users you need to do something which separate each user it could be on the bases of it's unique id,username,usergroup...etc.

USER GUIDE REFERENCE : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/

That's my login page as per my application requirements

```
public function login() 
{
    $data = $this->data;   
    if(isset($this->session->userdata('user_id')))
    {
        redirect('dashboard');
    }
    $this->form_validation->set_rules(
                                    'username', 'Username',
                                    'required|min_length[5]'
    );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules(
                                    'password', 
                                    'Password', 
                                    'trim|required|min_length[6]'
    );   
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
         $this->template->set('title', 'Login');
         $this->template->load('main', 'contents' , 'login', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');  

        if ($this->main_model->resolve_user_login($username, $password)) 
        {
            $user_id = $this->main_model->get_user_id_from_username($username);
            $user    = $this->main_model->get_user($user_id);        

            $this->session->user_id      = (int)$user->id;
            $this->session->username     = (string)$user->username;
            $this->session->name         = (string)$user->name;
            $this->session->password     = (string)$user->password;
            $this->session->created_at   = (bool)$user->created_at;
            $this->session->blog_id      = (bool)$user->blog_id;   
            $this->session->logged_in    = (bool)true;
            redirect('dashboard');
        } 
        else 
        {
             $this->template->set('title', 'Login');
             $this->template->load('main', 'contents' , 'login', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reference!